# django - reusing functions in many views

Tags: django, django-views

I have a bunch of functions that I created in some views that must be reused in many other views. Do I need to create a class and put those functions in a class? If yes how exactly has to be done in Django and then how do I call and initiate them in the new views?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django views are just Python functions.  You can call other Python functions from them just as you can from any other Python code.  Put your functions into a .py file, import it, and invoke the functions.

Of course, it may make sense for other reasons to create a class to hold the functions, but you certainly don't need to in order to call them from views.

Comment: Let's say if I create a file in the root of my django project called myfunctions.py and put my functions in there, how do I call them in my views?

Answer (score 4):

The solution would be to create the myfunctions.py file in your app folder and import it in your views. Your views file would look like:

```
import myfunctions

def my_view(request):
    .....
    foo = myfunctions.bar()
    ....
```

Comment: I did something like foo = myfunctions.bar() but all I need is to run myfunctions.bar() as it was there on my new view. Right now nothing happens when I do foo = myfunctions.bar().

Answer (score 2):

You look to complicated to Django. Django is just another Python application and lives in the Python world. For example you can create file library.py and import this file where is needed (in modules where the function from library is needed). If you need you library's functions to get data from database, just import models in the library.py and use them.

Django doesn't have such a big think as "module". You creating the architecture, you can define what in your case is module. In general this is just simple directory with **init**.py file inside to be able to import files from there.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, if you have a lot of functions that are widely used in your project it make sense put all this in some separate application. I create some module named 'contrib' for this purposes. It can avoid some time for maintaining this code in future

Comment: How do I crate my own module in django?

Comment: In fact module cat be just a directory what contains __init__.py file, you can put your code where and import this in future like 'from my_module import something' or puth this in other file 'from my_module.module_file import something'

Comment: How do I instantiate functions in the new view then?