# How to create a function is views.py so that all the functions inside the views.py can use it

Tags: python, django

Hi I have the following definition

```
if GroupProfile.objects.filter(id=self.request.session['ACL_gid'], permissions__codename='view_page'):
    context['can_view_page'] = 1
else:
    context['can_view_page'] = 0
return context
```

I am using this part of code in many of my views. How can I define it once so that I dont need to use it every time?

Comment: put it into a middleware maybe?

Comment: have a look at this might me helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909473/django-reusing-functions-in-many-views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply write function in any common file like,

```
def your_func(args):
 #do your work
```

and simply import it wherever you want to use it like a normal python function.
eg. `from common import your_func`

Answer (score 0):

a) You can create your a method inside your model or in Modelmanager(I think it would be most elegant solution):

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def can_view_page(self, acl_gid, perm_code = 'view_page'):
        return 1 if self.filter(id=acl_gid, permissions__codename=perm_code) else 0


class GroupProfile(models.Model):
    .....
    objects = MyManager()
```

b) You can create just a function in something like utils.py.
c) You can create a Mixin class and put there this function. You can always do there something like:

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['can_view_page'] = 1 GroupProfile.objects.filter(id=self.request.session['ACL_gid'], permissions__codename='view_page') else 0
        return context
```

But I'm not a big fan of this approach since it `overrides` instead of `extend` - it isn't really transparent in my opinion.

d) You can create a decorator!) But I don't think it is very right case to use it.

Comment: How do I pass this it into my views.py Andrey?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), and then add it to your `TEMPLATES` setting. The context provider is something very simple:

```
from .models import GroupProfile

def view_page(request):
    if GroupProfile.objects.filter(id=self.request.session['ACL_gid'],
                                   permissions__codename='view_page').count():
       return {'can_view_page': 1}
    return {'can_view_page': 0 }
```

Save this file somewhere; ideally inside an app (the same place where you have the `models.py` file) and then add it to your [`TEMPLATES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES), make sure you don't override the defaults.

Once you set this up, then all your templates will have a `{{ can_view_page }}` variable; and you don't have to keep repeating code in your views.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors is the updatd link